# JavaScript: POST to page several times at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to do POST to the site several times in loop, at the exact same time.
But what's happening now, is that it waits until the first is finished, and then makes a POST for the next `allsounds` and Delay is created.

**CODE:**

```
var allsounds = ["sound.wav","adom.wav","alarm.wav","tiny.wav","calm.wav","tiny4.wav","tiny5.wav","tiny4.wav",""];

  for (var i = 0; i < allsounds.length; i++) {
      $.post("alerts.php", {zone: zone, list: allsounds[i]});

      $.post("alerts1.php", {zone: zone, list: allsounds[i]});

      $.post("alerts2.php", {zone: zone, list: allsounds[i]});

}
```

Comment: So are you saying that `$.post` is executing synchronously in your code? `$.post` is asynchronous.  Try inserting `console.log('abc')` after each `$.post` call and you will see them executing immediately.

Comment: Possible you're testing this on localhost or another machine that is only executing one request at a time?

Comment: Watch the Network tool in your browser's Developer Tools and find out what is really happening. Often there is a limit on how many concurrent Ajax requests you can send to the same server. And/or the server may have limited capacity, or limits on how many concurrent requests it will process from the same client. My point is, maybe the requests are being queued. The network tool can show you the exact pattern of behaviour

Comment: But anyway why do you want to post the exact same data to three scripts on the same server?  It seems very inefficient. Or is the above code a contrived example which is hiding some real life complexity? It would seem more efficient to simply post the whole array of data to one endpoint in one single request (not even one per array  item... just **one** request) and then the server can process it all at once and do whatever it needs to. I don't see the purpose of the loop or the multiple requests.